# Will these floor joists support a new soaker tub installation?

Tags: floor, bathtub, joists

I am installing a 3ft. X 6ft. soaker bath tub that will weigh almost 1200 lb. dead weight when filled with water.  The tub will be parallel to two existing 2x10 floor joists that have a 11ft. 3in. span.

Will the existing floor joists support the 1200 lb. load or do I need to sister both of the existing floor joists with a new 2x10 floor joist?

Comment: I think something is wrong. If water weighs 62.3 lbs. pcf I calculate the tub to be only 1’ high. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How tall is the tub?

Comment: @LeeSam - perhaps it's okay - [typical tub 12", soaker 14" - according to QualityBath.com](https://www.qualitybath.com/discover/post/18020/soaking-tubs-everything-need-know)..  And don't forget the human in the bath will cause 2-3cf of displacement (so another 10-15% of depth).

Comment: @BudCrocker how far apart are the floor joists - 12",18",24" something else?

Answer (score 1):

A 2x10 spanning 11’ can support a total load of about 2000 lbs., depending on the species and grade, which is enough.

If you add 2 people to the load (assuming both weigh about 200 lbs. each) then the total load is 1200 lbs. plus 400 lbs. = about 1600 lbs.

There are issues about other people walking around the tub, but there are also issues about increasing the allowable load based on impact loading and you’ll be using two joists.

So, using two 2x10’s is more than adequate. Enjoy your tub. (Oh, with that kind of loading, be sure to use solid blocking at the bearing points.)

Comment: Just to be clear, "using the two 2x10s" means the two _existing_ joists, not adding two additional ones, correct?

Comment: @FreeMan That’s correct, as long as both joists are located under the tub and the tub is filled about 12”.